# Batch moving files using the file name in a nested folder search

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, search

I have a multitude of subtitles (.srt) files which I have in a directory, say C:\foo. I have a collection of video files, organised into a multitude of folders (i.e. folders named A, B, C, D, E, ... etc, which **each** have one to many video files). I would like to move each and every one of the .srt files to the folder that contains their matching (based on filename) video file?

Is there any way I can perform a substring search based on the .srt's filename, where it will search through the root directory folder (the root folder containing **folders** are **uniquely named** A, B, C, D, E, etc) and search also ALL the layers of sub-directories within that? i.e. all the nested sub-directories, to find a 'matching' video filename?

And from there, **if** there is a **match**, **moves** the .srt file TO the folder where the video file with the 'match' was found.

I suppose it would be akin to how media players can perform a fuzzy search and so even if any substring of the subtitle's name matches the video, it will load the subtitle)?

Now, noting this, I obviously don't require a fuzzy search implementation, because fortunately my file names are like this:

.srt filename: `XXX`_`abczxy`.srt

Video filename: `XXX`.mp4

where `XXX` = a string (in which this string is **exactly the same** **for both** the .srt and the video file)

and

where `abcxyz` = some unique, random string

Thanks

So far I have written:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "SEARCH_IN_DIR=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\foo\"
SET "DEST_DIR=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\RootFolder"

REM: Enter recursive search, display lists of files to be copied, copy from the source to the dest:
FOR /R "%SEARCH_IN_DIR%" %%f IN (%%a) (
    IF EXIST %%f (
    DO (
        xcopy /I "%%~f" "%DEST_DIR%" 2> NUL
    ) 
    ELSE (
        echo
    )
)
```

Comment: Considering that you want to work with substrings, vanilla batch files seem unlikely to be a solution. You probably want to look into PowerShell or a third-party language like Python (which, for my money, is both easy and has excellent string tools).

Comment: Thanks. Let's say they were exactly the same file name (I will rename each file accordingly), albeit different file extension of course. Could you then be able to assist with a vanilla batch file to assist with performing the above?